# recognizing cells in excel and change them to another format?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a bunch of student data (520 students) that I use a scanner to put data into excel (student's laps around the track). When the data is put in excel it shows up as the student's ID # rather than the student's name. Is there a way to format excel so that any time it sees a student's ID # it recognizes it as the student and changes it to their name?

i.e. John Doe is assigned ID # K97254. I down load scanner data into excel and any time K97254 shows up in excel, is there a way to have it show as John Doe?

Hope this is as clear as mud.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's possible to do this kind of thing with formatting, but it would get insane for 520 students, and probably exceed Excel's limitations.  The approach BrianC suggests is the logical way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it this way:

1. Make a spreadsheet containing two columns: one containing IDs and the other containing corresponding names.
2. Create another spreadsheet (or open an existing one), use a function such as VLOOKUP that references the ID # in the spreadsheet you created above, and returns the name contained in the same row, but second column of that spreadsheet.

For example:

I'll call the spreadsheet referred to in #1 Sheet1, and the spreadsheet referred to in #2 Sheet2. Both are assumed to be in the same workbook.

Sheet1 contains the following data:

```
       A       B
  1 K97254  John Doe
  2 K12345  Jane Smith
  3 K93784  Steve Someguy
  4 K37474  Stacy Somegirl
```

Let's say Sheet2 contains the ID K97254 in cell A3, and we want cell B3 to contain "John Doe" automatically. So we put this function into cell B3:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

So, VLOOKUP will search for K97254 in column A on Sheet1, and if it exists, will return the name in column B on Sheet1.

I'll break that down a little bit:

- `=VLOOKUP` refers to the function we're using, and the arguments are encapsulated within the parentheses.
- Since `A3` contains the ID we want to find, we'll use that as the first argument. In this function, the first argument is called the "lookup value".
- The second argument is the "table array". We want to use data from 2 sequential columns (A and B) in Sheet1, so we'll type `Sheet1!A:B` here.
- The third argument is the "column index number". Since we want to return data in the 2nd column of the table array we selected (Column B), we'll put `2` here.
- Finally, we want to find an exact match of the ID (note, not case-sensitive). The fourth argument should be `FALSE`, which tells VLOOKUP to return data only if there is an exact match.

You can copy that function to anywhere in column B, and it should perform a lookup for the corresponding value in column A.

I suppose you could also design a macro that actually replaces the ID data in the spreadsheet, but that might be needlessly overcomplicated, especially if your IDs are already contained in one column.

This Office [support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) goes over VLOOKUP in more detail, and gives another example that's similar to what you're asking about.

Comment: Good point, I elaborated as much as my time allowed. Hope that's better.